# How can I get backbone.js to send cookies when making model related rest calls?

Tags: cookies, backbone.js

I am using backbone to talk to my app running in Google App engine and I want to leverage google's built in authentication. Unfortunately this requires me to send the authentication cookie with all requests. Backbone does not seem to be sending the cookies by default.

Is there a way I can get backbone to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Backbone just uses jQuery's `ajax` function to do all of it's AJAX stuff, and all of the methods involved take options which they then pass on to `$.ajax`.  So, I don't know exactly how you specify `use the Google App engine cookie` specifically, but if you read the app engine documentation and the jQuery `$.ajax` documentation it shouldn't be hard to figure out.

Once you have figured that you, you just pass the option to your method.  For instance, if you're doing a fetch then something like:

```
someModel.fetch({cookies: ['appengine.google.com']});
```

should do the trick.

Honestly though, cookie sending is normally handled by the browser, and I don't even see any cookie options on the jQuery page ... are you sure this is a problem with Backbone and not a problem with setting the cookies in the first place?

Comment: I thought so to, I have just confirmed that the JS request from backbone does not contain any cookies. All other requests seem to send cookies. Do you know id there is a setting in backbone that would stop it sending cookies? (If its not clear I am a JS newbie)

Comment: As far as I know Backbone does nothing at all with cookies (the word "cookie" doesn't even appear anywhere in the Backbone code).  Generally speaking cookies are set on a per domain basis, and then automatically transmitted with every request.  If you're not doing anything special to prevent them from sending, then really your problem has to either be: A) with setting the cookie in the first place, or B) with domain issues (ie. you set the cookie at foo.com, but then you make an AJAX request to bar.com).

Comment: It was a domain issue, I was using two domains interchangeably (dev.app.appspt... & app.appspot...) which mapped to the same server but messed up cookies.

Comment: Good to hear that you were able to figure it out :-)